# 2010 Excel VBA, how to define fixed columns and variable rows copying data from multiple files in one file (Open All Excel Files In A Folder).

Tags: excel, vba

2010 Excel VBA, how to define fixed columns and variable rows (array) copying data from multiple files into one file (Open All Excel Files In A Folder).

My code example is below.  The code works but has gaps in the output data because the numerous Excel files have variable Columns defined and not all of those columns have data (gaps in the data when it is defined).

Columns A and C always have data in every file.
Columns B and D may have no data in certain cells.
Columns E and F may or may not be defined and may or may not contain data.

I need to copy fixed columns A through D only & copy to variable length of rows.

Thanks.

```
Sub LoopThroughFilesInFolder()
Dim mainwb As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim i As Integer

Set mainwb = ThisWorkbook
Set FileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'use path to the folder
Set FOlderObj = FileSystemObj.GetFOlder("E:\1-Chris Micha Master\DDTs all 2015 April 8\DDT Excel files")

'loop through the files
For Each fileobj In FOlderObj.Files

If fileobj.Name <> "OpenAllExcelFilesInAFolder.xlsm" And fileobj.Name <> "~$OpenAllExcelFilesInAFolder.xlsm" And (FileSystemObj.GetExtensionName(fileobj.Path) = "xls") Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileobj.Path)

'copy the results from the just opened workbook
wb.Worksheets("DTCs").Select
lastcell = Range("A1:XFD1048576").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address
Range("A6:" & lastcell).Select
Selection.Copy

'go to the mainworkbook and paste data
mainwb.Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
If Range("a6").Value = "" Then
Range("a1").Select
Else
Range("a6").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
End If

ActiveSheet.Paste
Kwb.Activate
wb.Save
wb.Close
mainwb.Activate
End If
Next fileobj
End Sub
```